# Can MIME types of Github Pages files be configured?

Tags: html5-video, mime-types, mp4, github-pages

We have an MP4 video file in a Github Pages repository. The file is being served with a MIME type of `application/octet-stream`, which means Internet Explorer doesn't like it. It should be served as type `video/mp4`. Is there a way to configure Github Pages to use the proper MIME type, or should we find an alternate hosting solution for the video? This topic isn't addressed in the [help pages](https://help.github.com/categories/20/articles).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever get this resolved @pjmorse?

Comment: I'm almost six years and two jobs along now - I don't even remember which project was having this problem.

Comment: Fair enough; I know how that goes :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no.

However, [Ian's earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16411902) is not strictly true. You can use github to host webpages. There are plenty of developer blogs up there.

For video I use Amazon s3 as it costs next to nothing for storing and serving video content and you can set the mimetypes as you require.

I store about 60GB of video and served 8GB last month for the cost of 9USD so it's worth it.

Answer (score 13):

The topic is addressed here: https://help.github.com/articles/mime-types-on-github-pages/

> GitHub Pages supports more than 750 MIME types across 1,000s of file
>   extensions. The list of supported MIME types is generated from the
>   [mime-db project](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db), which aggregates MIME types from the Apache and Nginx
>   projects as well as the official IANA list of internet content types.
>
> [MIME types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) are additional headers that servers send to provide
>   browsers with information about the types of files being requested and
>   how to handle the file once downloaded.
>
> To add or modify MIME types for use on GitHub Pages, see the [mime-db
>   Contributing instructions](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db#adding-custom-media-types).

The mime-db project is currently reporting `mp4` as `video/mp4`:

```
"video/mp4": {
  "source": "apache",
  "compressible": false,
  "extensions": ["mp4","mp4v","mpg4"]
},
```

Source: https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db/blob/46a40f0524a01fb3075a7ecde92e8e04fc93d599/db.json#L6233

If Github pages is still reporting `mp4` files as `application/octet-stream` you should contact Github support.

Answer (score -26):

You're not supposed to use Github as a webserver, because it is a code hosting site. They manage your code repositories and are only concerned about showing code.

Comment: So your answer to the actual question is, "No, the MIME types cannot be configured"?

Comment: @pjmorse asked about GitHub Pages, which is specifically designed to be used as a webserver, not the GitHub repository browser.